# Share resources between map/reduce

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Does running map task slows down the reduce task? By slowing down I mean do they share a common resource?

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are going to affect the system in one way or another. They are both java processes running on the same machines. However, in system configurations these days, it's not that big of a deal as long as you don't do something stupid with the number of slots.

Each map task or reduce task itself isn't multithreaded or multi-processes, so it'll mostly only use one CPU core. This is why a general rule of thumb is 1 map or reduce slot per core makes a bit of sense. So, if you have 12 cores, you could do something like 8 map slots and 4 reduce slots.

Also, the tasks are going to be sharing the same disk, but this isn't that big of a deal either typically since systems have several disks and disk access comes in bursts.

The best way to figure out the best configuration is just try to try different configurations out. It's not hard to set the number of slots, so just tweak it and then rerun some production-representative jobs.

Note that if you are only running one job at a time, the reducers will not be doing much while the mappers are running. In which case, they won't really affect one another. More realistically, you'll have several jobs running and the map tasks of one job will be running at the same time as the other job's reducers.